# Два параллельных цикла на разных ядрах С++

Tags: c++, циклы, распараллеливание

Как запустить в одной программе два цикла, допустим, `while(true){...}` на разных ядрах, чтобы крутились в раз?

Comment: @illusion, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: OpenMP может пригодиться.

Answer (score 2):

Планировщик потоков операционной системы в большинстве случаев достаточно хорош, поэтому предоставьте ему самому распределить потоки по ядрам.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto func = [](string msg){ while(true) {cout << msg;} };

    thread th1(func, "1");
    thread th2(func, "2");

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Большинство умных ос самостоятельно разделят "тяжелые потоки" между разными ядрами. Но если хотите, можно подсказать системе. Для этого в windows есть функция [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), которая позволяет привязать поток к ядру/процессору.